# Div not clearing a container only in a 640 viewport and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get a container div I have to clear a sibling div I have. It works for a full desktop version, but when I get to about 640px the image shows up halfway over the div above it. I added a snippet in here, but for some reason my image isn't showing. I believe it is because of the plugin I am running.

This can be seen on my site here:
[click here](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index)

```css
.box-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 /*height: 800px;*/
 height: 100%;
}
.dark-blue-box, .light-blue-box {
 height: 50%;
 width: 25%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.dark-blue-box{
 /*background-color: #66b5c6; or !!!!!!!#45a5ba!!!!
 #8fc9d6
65%    #7dc0cf*/
 /*background-color: rgb(69, 165, 186);*/
 background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.light-blue-box {
 background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover, .light-blue-box:hover {
 background-color: purple;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-title, .light-blue-box:hover .box-title {
 color: #FFF;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description {
 display: none;
}
.dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
 display: block;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.insideBoxWrap {
 padding: 50px 18%;
}
.box-title {
 color: #307382;
 font-size: 3em;
}
.box-description {
 padding-top: 15px;
 color: #307382;
 font-size: 1.6em;
}
.box-description-hover {
 display: none;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(5), .dark-blue-box:nth-child(7){
 background-color: #8fc9d6;
}
.dark-blue-box:nth-child(5):hover, .dark-blue-box:nth-child(7):hover{
 background-color: purple;
}
.light-blue-box:nth-child(6), .light-blue-box:nth-child(8){
 background-color: #45a5ba;
}
.light-blue-box:nth-child(6):hover, .light-blue-box:nth-child(8):hover{
 background-color: purple;
}

/*---Home Img-----*/
.home-img {
 /*position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;*/
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.home-img img {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
.parallax-window {
   min-height: 600px;
    background: transparent;
}
.home-img-text {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 4em;
 text-align: center;
 top: 40%;
}
/*----------------------------------------------PHONE MEDIA QUERY 640--------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
 .box-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
 }
 .dark-blue-box, .light-blue-box {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
 .dark-blue-box:hover, .light-blue-box:hover {
  height: 100%;
 }
 .dark-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover, .light-blue-box:hover .box-description-hover {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding-top: 20px;
 }
 .dark-blue-box:nth-child(5), .dark-blue-box:nth-child(7){
  background-color: #45a5ba;
 }
 .light-blue-box:nth-child(6), .light-blue-box:nth-child(8){
  background-color: #8fc9d6;
 }
 .insideBoxWrap {
  padding: 30px 30px;
 }
 .box-title {
  font-size: 1.6em;
 }
 .box-description {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/parallax.js-1.3.1/parallax.js"></script>
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="dark-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Brand Strategy</div>
      <div class="box-description">Digital Roadmap</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
   fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="light-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Development</div>
      <div class="box-description">That Outperforms</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
   fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="dark-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Visual Identity</div>
      <div class="box-description">That Is Timeless</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
   fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="light-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Interactivity</div>
      <div class="box-description">For Engagement</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
   fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="dark-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Responsive</div>
      <div class="box-description">Web Layout</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
   fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="light-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Ecommerce</div>
      <div class="box-description">Conversion Focused</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
   fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="dark-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Dynamic</div>
      <div class="box-description">Functionality</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
   fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="light-blue-box">
    <div class="insideBoxWrap">
      <div class="box-title">Illustration</div>
      <div class="box-description">All Hand-Made</div>
      <div class="box-description-hover">Hover View fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs
   fdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfsfdsf fdfsd fdsfds fdfsdf fdsfdsf fdsfdsf fdsfs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div>
 fdsgfdsfadsg <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<div class="home-img">
 <!--<img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/try.jpg" alt=""> -->
 <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/try.jpg">
  <div class="home-img-text">Quality Solutions</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div>
 fdsgfdsfadsg <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you maybe apply classes to the container and sibling divs you are referring to, so that we can see which ones you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, I could have swore I wrote that in. The home-img container is going over the sibling div above it and the box-container div.